# How are confidence scores calculated in AWS SageMaker GroundTruth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

AWS's SageMaker/GroundTruth Labelling jobs return a [confidence score](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-output.html#sms-output-confidence) for each human-annotated label.
However, the score is not a direct function of the responses of the N workers who labeled the task.
For example, on tasks with all three workers assigning different labels the score varies (0.61, 0.55, 0.68). And where 2/3 agree, the score varies also (0.95, 0.91).

"Automated data labelling" is disabled, which indicates that all items are labeled by a human, rather than being fully/partially automatically classified.

How does AWS calculate these confidence scores?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the details, so leaving this question open hoping for a real answer. But this is what I can find out so far:

Each labelling job has a [AnnotationConsolidationConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_AnnotationConsolidationConfig.html) param which lets you control how the confidence score is calculated using an AWS Lambda function.

The default for single-image classification is described as:

> a variant of the Expectation Maximisation approach.
> It estimates parameters for each worker and uses Bayesian inference to estimate the true class based on the class annotations from individual workers."

however it appears regular AWS users are not able to view the function itself due to lack of permissions.